# Is it possible in jenkins to keep just first and last failures in "a row" of consecutives failures?

Tags: jenkins

I have a Jenkins pipeline that periodically (each 1-hour) checks the correct deployment of a given infrastructure.

For tracing/auditing I'm just interested in keeping "build" changes when the execution changes from "success execution" to "failure". That's is, if I have a history of:

```
OK, OK, OK, OK, KO, KO, KO, KO, OK, OK, OK, OK, KO, KO, OK
^               ^               ^               ^       ^
exec            exec            exec            exec    exec
status          status          status          status  status
change          change          change          change  change
```

What I would really like to keep is the builds corresponding only to the execution status change (and automatically remove all others).

```
OK,             KO,             OK,             KO,     OK
^               ^               ^               ^       ^
exec            exec            exec            exec    exec
status          status          status          status  status
change          change          change          change  change
```

Is that history-saving policy possible in Jenkins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Add a [groovy post-build](https://plugins.jenkins.io/groovy-postbuild/) step to your job that will remove old builds as you desire.

I use such an approach to discard all successful builds of a job except for the last 3 ones (since typically, you're more interested in the failed runs), using this post-build script:

```
def allSuccessfulBuilds = manager.build.project.getBuilds().findAll {
    it.result?.isBetterOrEqualTo( hudson.model.Result.SUCCESS )
}

allSuccessfulBuilds.drop(3).each {
  it.delete()
}
```

You can modify this snippet to implement your custom deletion strategy.